# Apex Decimal Division, Gives wrong output

Tags: apex, division

```
Decimal a = 60000.000;
Decimal b = 2000.0000;
system.debug(a/b);
```

Expected Output: **30**

Actual:
[image]

Is there anything did I miss? Why this weird behavior?

Comment: But is not 3E+1 same as 3*10^1 => 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question comments by kurunve 30E+1 is same as 30 but still if you want to see 30 in the debug logs you can either round the output to nearest integer by using `Math.round(decimalValueHere)` or if decimal points are required then you may use set scale as below:

```
Decimal a = 60000.000;
Decimal b = 2000.0000;
system.debug((a/b).setScale(4));

//output: 30.0000 as we have set scale to 4
```

Comment: Do you know the exact reason why 30 is represented as 3E+1 only in some cases?

Comment: I would say since you are computing higher numbers, so just to consume less space it uses 3E+1 but it just debug logs doesn't matter if it shows 30 or 3E+1, your other calculations won't get impacted because of this, or if you want to display it on any custom page it won't come as 3E+1, may I know the exact reason you want 30 instead of 3E+1?